# php code to convert total number of days to month

Tags: php

I have total number of trial period in a days.

For example, if i set 60 days as a trial period, then it needs to display 2 month

If i set 45 days as a trial period, then it needs to display 1 month and 15 days.

How can we convert to total number of days to month using php?

Comment: This is a maths question...

Answer (score 1):

This code isn't really correct (and month not always have 30 days, but that's like your example is) but it does what you want:

```
$days = floor($totalDays / 30);
$months = $totalDays % 30;
echo $months . " months and " . $days . " days";
```

Comment: It looks to me like you have the right idea, but got the months and days the wrong way around.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware swap the variable name declarations then it should work